# how to convert mentioned java object to a list objects in java. The java object has internally a list which contains object of same type

Tags: java, object, data-conversion

**My Pojo calls:**

```
package com.ecosys.smartbuild.bean;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    
public class ProgressAndDatesStructure {

private String id;

private String startDate;

private String endDate;

private String progress;

private ProgressAndDatesStructure progressandDatesStructure[];

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the startDate
 */
public String getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

/**
 * @param startDate the startDate to set
 */
public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

/**
 * @return the endDate
 */
public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

/**
 * @param endDate the endDate to set
 */
public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

/**
 * @return the progress
 */
public String getProgress() {
    return progress;
}

/**
 * @param progress the progress to set
 */
public void setProgress(String progress) {
    this.progress = progress;
}

/**
 * @return the progressandDatesStructure
 */
public ProgressAndDatesStructure[] getProgressandDatesStructure() {
    return progressandDatesStructure;
}

/**
 * @param progressandDatesStructure the progressandDatesStructure to set
 */
public void setProgressandDatesStructure(ProgressAndDatesStructure[] progressandDatesStructure) {
 this.progressandDatesStructure = progressandDatesStructure;
}
```

**My object:**

```
ProgressAndDatesStructure [id=PRJ-0000001, startDate=null, endDate=null, progress=null,

progressandDatesStructure=[ProgressAndDatesStructure [id=PRJ-0000001.1, startDate=2019-05-16T02:30:00.000Z, endDate=2019-09-18T11:30:00.000Z, progress=50.00,

progressandDatesStructure=[ProgressAndDatesStructure [id=PRJ-0000001.1.1, startDate=2019-05-16T02:30:00.000Z, endDate=2019-08-18T11:30:00.000Z, progress=50.00,

progressandDatesStructure=null], ProgressAndDatesStructure [id=PRJ-0000001.1.2, startDate=2019-07-16T02:30:00.000Z, endDate=2019-09-18T11:30:00.000Z, progress=50.00,

progressandDatesStructure=null]]], ProgressAndDatesStructure [id=PRJ-0000001.2, startDate=2019-03-16T02:30:00.000Z, endDate=2019-08-18T11:30:00.000Z, progress=25.00,

progressandDatesStructure=[ProgressAndDatesStructure [id=PRJ-0000001.2.1, startDate=2019-04-16T02:30:00.000Z, endDate=2019-08-18T11:30:00.000Z, progress=25.00,

progressandDatesStructure=null], ProgressAndDatesStructure [id=PRJ-0000001.2.2, startDate=2019-03-16T02:30:00.000Z, endDate=2019-07-18T11:30:00.000Z, progress=25.00,

progressandDatesStructure=null]]], ProgressAndDatesStructure [id=PRJ-0000001.3, startDate=2019-05-16T02:30:00.000Z, endDate=2019-09-18T11:30:00.000Z, progress=70.00,

progressandDatesStructure=[ProgressAndDatesStructure [id=PRJ-0000001.3, startDate=2019-05-16T02:30:00.000Z, endDate=2019-09-18T11:30:00.000Z, progress=70.00,

progressandDatesStructure=null]]]]]
```

I need the list of `progressandDatesStructure` objects. It can have any number of internal `progressandDatesStructure` objects, but I need the simple list of object which contains `id`, `startdate`, `enddate` and `progress` only.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and also [edit] your question to make it nicely readable. That being said, what's the problem with looping over the elements with some recursion and adding the elements to a list? If you want the list elements to not contain the nested arrays and don't want to just use `null` you might need to create a different class for that (e.g. a super class that contains only the fields while the subclass adds the array).

Comment: i will create a new class but i'm not sure how many times to run a loop. their might be 'n' objects inside a object and inside that object their might be 'n' more objects again for multiple times. look my pojo and string object you might get an idea

Comment: Well, the beauty of lists is that their length is dynamic so you don't need to know that beforehand. The arrays also have a `length` attribute which tells you how often you should be able to loop over it or you could just use a "foreach" loop like `for(ProgressAndDatesStructure element : progressandDatesStructure)`. Of course if the array reference itself is `null` you wouldn't loop at all.

Comment: thats the issue i was talking about...how many for-each loops to  use. As inside my progressandDatesStructure their is a list of progressandDatesStructure.In the similar way their are many object list inside the object. it's like hierarchy Can you please look into my object carefully

Comment: Please read my first comment carefully as I have already addressed this: "with some recursion" - if you don't know recursion yet, look it up. Basically you'd call the same function that collects one element into the list for each of the nested elements. Just make sure that you skip any already added elements if your arrays might form cycles (e.g. A -> B -> C -> A).